# How to display custom Apex class Object in VisualForce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following class : -

```
public class Comment {
    Integer postId{get;set;}
    Integer id {get;set;}
    String name{get;set;}
    String email{get;set;}
    String body{get;set;}
    public Comment(Integer postId, Integer id, String name, String email,String body){
        this.postId = postId;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

I want to display a list of Comment objects in Visualforce is there a way to implement it or should  just create a Salesforce comment object?
I am hitting a rest API to get the data and parsing it to a POJO class.

My VisualForce page : -

```
<apex:page controller="CommentController" >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!comments}" var="comm">
            <apex:column value="{!comm.name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!comm.Id}"/>
        </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!previous}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!next}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you please show full code for your `CommentController`

Comment: How is comments getting populated (to ytiq's point above)

Comment: until you add actual code, I think you need to have `public` on fields

Comment: @ytiq I added public to all the fields and it worked.

Comment: ok, I'll add it as an answer, so we can close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `public` to your DTO class properties like this

```
public class Comment {
    public Integer postId{get;set;}
    public Integer id {get;set;}
    public String name{get;set;}
    public String email{get;set;}
    public String body{get;set;}

    public Comment(Integer postId, Integer id, String name, String email,String body){
        this.postId = postId;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Because in Visualforce you need `public` modifier to display information on UI